# ValueError: Unexpectedly found an instance of type `<class 'keras.layers.core.lambda_layer.Lambda'>`. Expected a symbolic tensor instance

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lambda, transfer-learning

I am trying to train a CIFAR10 dataset using transfer learning and a research paper used a resize technique but the functions change names. I am getting this error how can i fix this.

```
inputs = keras.Input(shape=(32, 32, 3))
upscale = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.image.resize(x, 160, 160, method= (tf.image.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR))(inputs))
densenet_model = tf.keras.applications.densenet.DenseNet121(include_top=False, pooling = max, input_tensor=upscale, input_shape=(160, 160, 3), weights='imagenet')
# when you change the input shape, keras will automatically change the shapes of the other layers accordingly . to meet the new input shape
densenet_model.summary()
x = densenet_model.output
x = keras.layers.Flatten()(x)
x = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu')(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = keras.layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
x = keras.layers.Dropout(0.3)(x)
x = keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')(x)
#output = keras.layers.Dense(units=10, activation='softmax')(x) # output layer with softmax activation
model = keras.Model(inputs=densenet_model.input, outputs=x)

for layer in densenet_model.layers:
    layer.trainable=False
```

ValueError: Unexpectedly found an instance of type `<class 'keras.layers.core.lambda_layer.Lambda'>`. Expected a symbolic tensor instance.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this issue , you need to modify `tf.image.resize()` in `Lambda layer` as below:

```
upscale = tf.keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: tf.image.resize(x, [160, 160],method=tf.image.ResizeMethod.BILINEAR))(inputs)
```